# How to put two images next to each other with a) and b) labels?

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats

I want to put two images next to each other and in order to do that I have written these code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}{16pc}
\includegraphics[width=16pc]{P_1.eps}
\caption{\label{fig4} Caption of the first image.
\end{minipage}\hspace{2pc}%
\begin{minipage}{16pc}
\includegraphics[width=16pc]{P_2.eps}
\caption{\label{fig4} Caption of the second image.
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

But in pdf I see

**Figure 4: Caption of the first image.   Figure 5: Caption of the second image.**

How I can change it so that it was

**Figure 4-a: Caption of the first image.   Figure 4-b: Caption of the second image.**

or

**Figure 4.a: Caption of the first image.   Figure 4.b: Caption of the second image.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `subcaption` package (a powerful companion to the [caption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{subfig}{\figurename~#1#2#3}
\DeclareCaptionSubType*{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{format=subfig,labelsep=colon,labelformat=simple}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \rule{4cm}{3cm}
    \caption{A subfigure}
    \label{fig:1a}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \rule{4cm}{3cm}
    \subcaption{Another subfigure}
    \label{fig:1b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{A figure with two subfigures}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 subcaption is the best option. Forget subfig and subfigure

Comment: Personally I would use `\renewcommand\subfigurename{\figurename}` (or `\renewcommand\subfigurename{Figure}`) after `\DeclareCaptionSubType*{figure}` instead of defining and using an own caption format called `subfig`, because this would make it possible to use other caption formats as well. I just see that I have forgotton to document this one (sorry for that), will do this in the very next version.

Comment: Why it requires so long code? Can't we have another simplified code like the answer of Thomas Connor is. I would use the code of Thomas Connor, but I worried because the subfigure package is considered obsolete.

Comment: @Narek: besides using an obsolete package (which is not advisable), the code in Thomas Connor's answer contains some typos and **does not** produce the headings that you required for the caption of the subfigures. The code I provided is not so long if you think of the benefits it provides.

Comment: @Narek, you can easily add a command that would get you code that looks the same as the code from Thomas Connor but that has the same result as the code from this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the package subfigure. The syntax is for instance:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \subfigure[caption (a)]{\includegraphics[width=16pc]{P_1.eps}}\label{...}}
  \subfigure[caption (b)]{\includegraphics[width=16pc]{P_2.eps}}\label{...}}
  \caption{general caption}
  \label{...}
\end{figure}
```

You will get the expected result.

Comment: @Tomas The `subfigure` package is considered obsolete; alternative options are the `subfig` or the `subcaption` packages. Besides, your code snippet contains superfluous closing braces and does not produce the labels for the subfigures that @Narek required.

Comment: @Gonzalo: Thanks for the advice! I'll check it.